# Xpath string replace/tranform

Tags: php

I'm trying to collect price data on items from one marketplace platform using XPath, which I don't know much. For example, on item page the price for item is $1.66M, while rendering the page I can scrape string like this : $1.99M, which I need to transform in the same XPath into the string like $1990000. So far, I managed only to select this element : `//span[contains(@class, "someClass")][position()>0<4]`

Really need your help. Pretty please!

Comment: This is not XPath issue... What language are you using: Python, Java etc?

Comment: PHP, but it's already build engine. I need somehow to fix this issue with Xpath, or, alternatively, by Regex while using it's as a selector. That's why it's such a pain.

Comment: It's absolutely NOT about the XPath. XPath is used to locate the element. Extracting the element text and converting the text to other formats are done by other tools / techniques.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Will tell that nothing can be done from this side. Thanks a lot for confirming it!